# OpenStack4j - maven unresolved dependencies

Tags: scala, maven, dependencies, openstack, openstack4j

In scala I am trying to use openstack4j library.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.pacesys" % "openstack4j" % "1.0.1"
```

I get following error/warning with unresolved dependencies. OpenStack4j is found
and installed, however indirectly depended modules org.glassfish.* are not.

```
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.pacesys#openstack4j;1.0.1!openstack4j.jar (1102ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-utils;2.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-locator;2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

What can I do to resolve this?